# Change the font family of <div class="mainmenu">?

Tags: css

I tried to change the family font of my mainmenu in website : http://www.train-luxe-afrique.com/

It doesn't work. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of CSS.

Comment: Yes of course. I try to put this code but don't work :.mainmenu {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1em;
border-top-width: 0;
text-transform: none;
padding: 12px;
  font-family: Old Standard ,sans-serif;}
.container_12 .grid_12 {
width: 965px;
}

Comment: go through this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp   hope this helps..

Comment: well you have 3 definitions `.dropcap, .iconbox32, .iconbox16, .mainmenu ul > li a, .camera_desc.heading, .filter_options ul li, .member_info .member_job, .a_member .social_title, .a_blogpost .social_links .share_text, .share-post, .work_heading, .a_work .social_links .share_text, .pricing_heading, .testimonial .who .name, .tabs > ul li a, .sc_button {
    font-family: 'QlassikMediumRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
}` and `.mainmenu > ul {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}` and `.mainmenu {
    font-family: Old Standard ,sans-serif;
}` odds are one's overwriting what you're trying to do

Comment: Please add example a shot source code example of your site!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem relates to specificity so in your style.css, just add the lines.

```
li.menu-item a{
    font-family: "whatever" !important;
}
```

The !important will override all other styles.

You should also try refactoring your code to make it less cluttered that way you won't have to use hacks like that.

Comment: Thanks for help. I apply this CSS code : .mainmenu ul li ul li a {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1em;
border-top-width: 0;
text-transform: none;
padding: 12px;
  font-family: Old Standard ,sans-serif;}
.container_12 .grid_12 {
width: 965px;
} and work. But the typo Old Standard have a problem with accent. Do you know typo with french accent ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking but maybe try and put the Old Standard font in quotes i.e `"Old Standard"`